# python subprocess popen starts immediately

Tags: python, linux, process

My goal is to be able to start shell script in separate process and inspect it by linux ptrace syscall.
The problem is that I need to get process PID before it even starts. Stuff like subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l']) or python-sh runs command immediately, so in a time I am trying to inspect this process by its PID it is likely finished.
On the other hand I cant use os.fork + exec because bash command I start overrides python code.

Comment: don't understand, why you cannot use fork + exec, because subprocess uses it internally.

Comment: on exec in forked process python dies to give live for new code (shell script for instance).

Comment: so since i did os.fork i can execute python only until exec command. Is there any way to exec bash in child, then immediately go back to parent and run some function on child pid?

Comment: How are you calling `ptrace()` anyway?  Do you use `ctypes` directly or something more high level like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ptrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Unix, I think that you can use the `preexec_fn` argument in the Popen constructor.

According to the documentation of subprocess:

> If preexec_fn is set to a callable object, this object will be called in the child process just before the child is executed. (Unix only)

As it runs in the child process, you can use `os.getpid()` to get the child pid.

Answer (score 2):

Just fork and before exec of the shell you call `ptrace()` with `PTRACE_TRACEME` so the exec doesn't start immediately, giving the parent all the time it needs to prepare before it tells the child to continue (`PTRACE_CONT`, `PTRACE_SYSCALL`, or `PTRACE_SINGLESTEP`).

When using `subprocess.Popen()` you may use the `preexec_fn` argument mentioned by @RuiSilva to do the `PTRACE_TRACEME` call.